# I am trying to access data from web API application(pulished at IIS) to console applicatication(VSExpress2013)

Tags: c#, .net, rest, console-application

I created a console application in VS express 2013 for desktop and pulished a Web API application in IIS. Now I am trying to access data from web API application by IIS in console application(in VS express 2013). but getting errors. please anyone having experience in this may help me. all the answer with new idea or any idea are accepted
you can see console application code on my github account link is
https://github.com/meta-pratap-ranawat/get2016/blob/WebAPI-Client-Certificate/Program.cs

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: problem is now solved #error was due to https connection #thanks for reply @CodingYoshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the webapi you will need to Use

`HttpClient` as described in the below link and please check the Post and Get availability on method.

Please refer [this link](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) for implementation.